# Restoring factory recovery partition (Samsung)

Tags: windows, partitioning, restore, recovery-partition

I have upgraded the hard disk in a Samsung laptop and would like to restore the "Press <kbd>F4</kbd> for recovery" partition.

My new disk has three partitions, `System`, `Windows`, and `Recovery`. I did a `dd` of the recovery partition from the old hard disk to the new. I also set the `diag` flag on the new hard disk. <kbd>F4</kbd> recovery still is not working.

TLDR: I mapped my new disk like my old disk with the exception of exact sizes. I did the recover partition from old to new via LiveCD. <kbd>F4</kbd> recovery does not work.

Comment: Did you duplicate the original hdd sector by sector or only selected partitions.  It sounds like the process you used was incorrect.

Comment: The selected partition.  The new hdd is smaller.  I did "dd if=/dev/sdc3 of=/dev/sda3 BS=512".  Why would you have to clone the entire disc?  You should be able to split or trash  your windows partition and have it still work

Comment: You clearly did something wrong, because it doesn't work, which is the reason I would copy the entire disk.

Comment: I got it.  I am going to do a writeup and post all the tools.  I basically found this Samsung utility that is a boot-able version of Samsung Recovery.  Using that I can repartition the HDD to Samsung's liking.  It installs a base recovery environment and restores press f4 ability.  Then I installed windows and used linux to copy the original recovery partition back (on a file level, not dd).  Check back here in a few weeks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original poster claims to have solved the issue and would post instructions 11+ years ago but never did. This question is effectively orphaned. “I am going to do a writeup and post all the tools. I basically found this Samsung utility that is a boot-able version of Samsung Recovery.”

Answer (score 1):

When I need to migrate a HDD to SSD.  I use the [Samsung Data Migration Software](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html). It's a great tool for moving all your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dd to do a full drive copy to this one and then use the recovery, as it sounds by doing only one partition, the MBR isn't being copied correctly, preventing the recovery from working.