# Is it really impossible to restore the recovery partition on samsung laptops?

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla

I bought a Samsung 900X3C and would like to get rid of the recovery partition since the disk is only 128 GB. But first I want to create a restorable image. However, samsung support says it's not possible. Can this be true? Or am i misinterpreting?

My plan was to use my external backup drive to back up the recovery partition, then delete it. In case I need to recover windows, I want to boot from a liveusb, and restore the image, then boot the recovery partition and reinstall.

I made a backup of the entire drive with clonezilla and was almost ready to go, however, I encountered this on [samsung support](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=349434&modelname=NP-900X3C-AU01&modelcode=&session_id=QnC1jpy0Z1cL1Qr5PQt9DmJndSrF9pq8Jw3jjq2vKTmQQQJZK6rN!222724522!1297608809!1348977397659&from_osc=):

> If the RECOVERY partition is deleted, Samsung Recovery Solution will
>   no longer function. Once deleted, there is no way to recreate the
>   RECOVERY partition.

Can this be true? Or is it just to scare people into leaving the recovery partition alone? Or is it a security measure, some way to prevent people from pirating win7? Is it possible that samsung could tell the difference between the original configuration and one restored by clonezilla, or even dd?

I know this might seem paranoid, but previously I've failed to restore recovery partition  on another computer when I upgraded the disk. That time i dded the entire drive, and it failed. It was definitively because of anti-piracy technology that time.

[This guy](https://superuser.com/questions/476558/restoring-factory-recovery-partition-samsung) tried and failed to restore the partition, but he clearly did something wrong, because he just backed up the one partition, and not the whole drive.

Comment: Why you don't make an image of the OS that you want to recover in case of damage and save it and then you could delete the recovery partition?

Comment: Meh, I never saw any value in a recovery partition.  If you make a backup of your system in its 'recovered' state, then you have what was in the partition anyway.

Comment: @Zoredache the unique value of recovery partition is for waranty, because if there are changes in the HDD or something like that, they don't respect waranty, maybe the solution is making a copy of the entire HDD and save it just in case

Comment: @poz2k4444 True, but in case I want to sell it, it would be nice to be able to reset it to "factory defaults", however, I might just use the recovery partition to restore computer, then make another image before booting it and then restoring my current configuration.

Comment: @bobbaluba Have you searched something that makes any image of the entire HDD?? It could be the solution for your problem, it's just I never do that, but I know it exists...

Comment: @poz2k4444 Isn't that what dd is for?

Comment: @bobbaluba well yes, but it is for linux OS, as far as I know, I don't think your computer have for default linux, does it?

Comment: @poz2k4444 Yes, but I always carry a linux live usb on my key chain. So it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Getting around this problem is making an "image" of your entire HDD, [here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/backupandimage.shtml) is something that you could use to start.

The other tip that I can give is to restore to factory settings, the make a single image of the operating system, and then back it up, so if you want to sell it later, you just use the restored image and voilà.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.